# UIPickerView - using custom views for multi-line rows - need layout advice

Tags: ios, user-interface, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView which will display a list of items for the user.  I'd like each item to be presented as multiple lines of text using a different font size for each line.  A rough mockup is shown below.  This will allow presenting more text than can fit in the single line of the default UIPickerView.

[image: mockup]

bdesham pointed me towards using the pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView in the delegate for the UIPickerView.  This seems to be the way to go as it'll let me provide my own custom view for the individual rows.

My thought was to create a UIView which had 2 UILabel subviews, one for each line of text.  This way I could apply a different font to each line.  I tried the below, but the layout doesn't seem to be working.  I need the lines to be one on top of the other.  The below was my attempt at floating the second line to the bottom via the mask.

```
#define VIEWTAG_LINE1 1
#define VIEWTAG_LINE2 2

- (UIView*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIView* v;
    if (view)
        v = view;
    else
    {
        v = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

        UILabel* l1 = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        l1.tag = VIEWTAG_LINE1;
        [v addSubview: l1];

        UILabel* l2 = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
        l2.tag = VIEWTAG_LINE2;
        l2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
        [v addSubview: l2];
    }

    UILabel* l1 = (UILabel*)[v viewWithTag: VIEWTAG_LINE1];
    l1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"row %d line 1", row];
    [l1 sizeToFit];

    UILabel* l2 = (UILabel*)[v viewWithTag: VIEWTAG_LINE2];
    l2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"row %d line 2", row];
    [l2 sizeToFit];

    [v sizeToFit];

    return v;
}
```

This produces the below.  Any suggestions on getting the two UILabel views so they're stacked on top of each other producing the desired multi-line result?

[image: multi-line attempt]

Comment: it might not work but have you tried sticking in a UITableViewCell instead of a simple UIView? because it does exactly what you are trying to do style wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the frames and font of the two labels.

```
    v = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

    UILabel* l1 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 24)] autorelease];
    li.font = [UIFont sytemFontOfSize:22]; // choose desired size
    l1.tag = VIEWTAG_LINE1;
    [v addSubview: l1];

    UILabel* l2 = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 24, 320, 16)] autorelease];
    l2.font = [UIFont sytemFontOfSize:14]; // choose desired size
    l2.tag = VIEWTAG_LINE2;
    [v addSubview: l2];
```

Adjust the labels' height as needed. Adjust the `y` origin of `l2` as needed.

Comment: Note that I had to remove the autoresizingMask line for it to work.  Using it as is still gave strange results.  The second line for the first row showed up in the second row, the second line for the second row showed up in the third row, etc.  Like the second line was pushed down too far.  Removing the autoresizingMask made it work  and show up as expected.

Comment: Should I be using something other than hard-coded values for the 320?  Also, using 0 for the x position still caused the label to overlap the left edge of the control graphics.  I changed it to 4 and that works, but I wonder if there's some place to query that from as opposed to hard-coding it.  Any idea?

Comment: Oddly I didn't even notice that call for the `autoresizingMask`. Sadly there's not a really good way to get more dynamic values for the frames. One thing that will help is to set the label's background color to the `clearColor`.

Comment: To clarify, I needed to remove the autoresizingMark and the sizeToFit calls for the labels and view.  Then it worked.

Comment: I'll just have to feel guilty then about the hard-coded values :)

Comment: The 320 get be replaced with the picker view's width. But there is no way to take into account picker's frame. Another option would be to make the label's width the same as the view's width and then set the label's autoresizingMask to "flexible width".

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's having this problem with Auto Layout, set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `YES` (which is the default value). I was setting it to `NO`, which was causing all the problems.