# UIPickerView - multi-line rows - need layout advice

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I want to make picker with 2 lines, I tried it like  [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395813/uipickerview-using-custom-views-for-multi-line-rows-need-layout-advice) , but I can not understand what I need to do: create a view and 2 label on it, when I add labels coordinates to code, but selection field still like it as default. How can I change  selection field size? And text in selection field have bigger size when other lines. Sorry for my english.

[image]

```
- (UIView*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
UIView* v;
if (view)
    v = view;
else
{
    v = [[UIView alloc] init] ;

    UILabel* l1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    l1.tag = 11;
    [v addSubview: l1];

    UILabel* l2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    l2.tag = 12;
    l2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    [v addSubview: l2];
}

UILabel* l1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 110, 35)];
l1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22]; // choose desired size
l1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"row %d line 1", row];

l1.tag = 11;
[v addSubview: l1];

UILabel* l2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 34 , 110, 35)];
l2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]; // choose desired size
l2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"row %d line 2", row];

l2.tag = 12;
[v addSubview: l2];

return v;
}
```

UPDATE

```
 - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  return yourViewHeight;
   }

 - (UIView*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
  UIView* v;
 if (view)
    v = view;
  else
  {
    v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 34, 110, 35)] ;

    UILabel* l1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    l1.tag = 11;
    [v addSubview: l1];

    UILabel* l2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    l2.tag = 12;
    l2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
    [v addSubview: l2];
}

UILabel* l1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 35)];
l1.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22]; // choose desired size
l1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"row %d line 1", row];

l1.tag = 11;
[v addSubview: l1];

UILabel* l2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 34 , 110, 35)];
l2.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]; // choose desired size
l2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"row %d line 2", row];

l2.tag = 12;
[v addSubview: l2];

return v;
}
```

http://i.picresize.com/images/2013/12/11/IiYqd.png

Comment: If you need help with some code you created, post the relevant code.

Comment: I fixed it and added image, sorry for this image I have no reputation to post like normal image

Comment: What is the height you are returning from this method?- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component {
  return yourViewHeight;
   }

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope It would work...

1. Implement this delegate method and return your view's height

> - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component{
>            return yourViewHeight;
>     }

1. Set frame for your label and your view..Frame of your label does not exceed the view's frame

> ```
> - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
>           //1. Create your view and set frame for the view 
>           //2. Create your label 1 and label 2 set the frame for your labels
>           //3. Add and return your view
>   }
> ```

Comment: `rowSizeForComponent` is not a delegate method you implement. It is a property of `UIPickerView` that you can set. And there is no data source method named `viewForRow:forComponent:`. It is named `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`.

Comment: @jailani habeeb,  view become better, but still not that I need, I updated first post. Or selected line can not be bigger or I need to make my label litter?

Comment: @jailani habeeb, oh, how be with background colour?

Comment: What is the height you are returning from this method?- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component { return yourViewHeight; }

Comment: v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 34, 110, 35)] ;        change this line as v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 70)] ;  and return - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component { return 70.0; }

Comment: Can I make row Height taller?

Comment: I got, but what about background? It is white not clear

Comment: Give clear color to your label like mylabel.backGroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

Comment: @jailani habeeb,ye, I just got and this, thx. but I got light colour on my first line, Is it possible to fix this i.picresize.com/images/2013/12/11/XJSyu.png ?

Comment: Do you actually want multiple component means columns In your picker ?

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:` picker view delegate method and return a height tall enough for your custom view.

You should also set the height of `v` in your `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView: method`.

And lastly, if you are reusing a view, don't keep adding more labels. They will already be there from the reused view.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 return 50;
}

than after

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
     UILabel *lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 310, 50)];
lblTitle.numberOfLines=2;
lblTitle.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
lblTitle.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];
lblTitle.text=[selectionList objectAtIndex:row];
}
return lblTitle;
```

}